# Resolve Argument Exception ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the code where where I am getting the exception.

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        int empId = Id++;
        Employees employees = new Employees();
        employees.AddEmployee(new Employee(empId, txtName.Text,              txtEmail.Text, txtMobile.Text, txtLandline.Text, txtWebsite.Text, txtAddress.Text));
        foreach (Employee employee in employees.GetList())
        {
            if (employee.Name.Equals(txtName.Text))
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = employee;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        contactsForm.Style.Add("display", "block");
    }
```

It is giving exception

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An invalid data source is being used for
> Repeater1. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or
> IEnumerable.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string LandLineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    
    public Employee(int id, string name, string email, string mobilenumber, string landlinenumber, string website, string address)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        MobileNumber = "+91 " + mobilenumber;
        LandLineNumber = landlinenumber;
        Website = website;
        Address = address;
    }
}
public class Employees
{
    List<Employee> ListOfEmployee = new List<Employee>();
    public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        ListOfEmployee.Add(employee);
    }
    public List<Employee> GetList()
    {
        return ListOfEmployee;
    }
}
```

This is the employee class.

How can I resolve that exception.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MobileNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is the .aspx code

Answer (score 0):

The repeater is expecting a collection, but you are passing it only one object.  Give this a try.

```
if (employee.Name.Equals(txtName.Text))
{
      Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Employee>(){ employee }.AsEnumerable();
      Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
var filteredEmployees = employees.GetList().Where(p=> p.Name.Equals(txtName.Text)).ToList();
Repeater1.DataSource = filteredEmployees;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```